# Closing Deleted Duplicates

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

When looking at [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/353506/) you can see discussion about the closure of this question.

Specifically, it quickly got custom flagged as "Duplicate of deleted question by the same user."

In terms of actual site performance, this question is mostly semantics; but I am still curious on the procedure.

Should this be used as a close reason?

The way I see it, because the other question is deleted, we should not vote to close as "Duplicate of deleted".  I'd think it would be more reasonable to *flag* as duplicate of deleted, and vote to close for the direct reason if there is one.

I could not find any discussion on this; so I was just curious on what method would be "more correct" on physics.se.

Comment: oups... I deleted my comments under the main question in an effort to clean up but this messes up some references in this question.  I originally suggested a recently deleted question that has been reposted by the same poster without change be deleted making a custom reason as "duplicate of deleted question".

Comment: FWIW: The phrase _duplicate of deleted question_ refers to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/353500/2451

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You cannot actually vote to close as duplicate of a deleted question.
2. If the asker of the non-deleted question is not the same as that of the deleted question, there is no need to do anything.
3. If the asker of both questions is the same user, then you should raise a moderator flag explaining that this user deleted a question and reposted it. This behaviour is generally frowned upon since it is often used to evade downvotes (receive a downvote, delete the question and post it anew with a fresh score of 0) or close votes. Usually a moderator will undelete the earlier question and then close as duplicate.